# xcode sumbission the application you have selected does not exist

Tags: ios, xcode, submission

[image]

Has anyone seen such an error ? What does it mean ?

- It was an update of already existed app.
- Xcode automatically manage provisioning profiles.
- Xcode 6.3.2
- OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Comment: I have the same problem here..

Comment: Yep, same.  Must be a problem at Apple's end.  There have been a lot of those recently...

Comment: I just received the same error.  It was working earlier today so it must be an intermittent problem.

Comment: I encountered this issue today too, and I try to upload with Application Loader still fail, but got more informations. Got a list of ERROR ITMS-90062 " This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString [x.x.x] in the Info.plist file.
it loops via all the library I imported using cocoapod. And those bundle Version in pod library < my target versions....

Comment: Upload did work with Application loader but after upload we are having another issue. When app is ready for external testing. And we choose "Add build to test". After filling all required fields. Next button click doesn't work. It just reloads. Did anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use Application Loader (https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg)

Had the same problem with Xcode 6.4, but went thru using Application Loader

Or you can open it from Xcode -> Open Developer Tools -> Application Loader

Answer (score 2):

I finally got my binary uploaded to iTunesConnect.

1. Archive your app in Xcode as normal. (I'm still using 6.2)
2. In Organizer, select the archive, Export, select Ad Hoc or App Store. This saves an .ipa file.
3. Open AppLoader, select "Deliver Your App", click "Choose", select the .ipa file from step 2.  Follow the prompts.

Notes

- Going this route, you won't need to recreate the In-App-Purchase that AppLoader expects when you start from scratch.
- I got a warning that the API analysis file being too large, but I think that can be safely ignored.
- The uploaded binary has a warning that the entitlement for TestFlight Beta testing is missing, but I don't use that, and it can also be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you have xcode < 7.x then you are going to face this problem..What fixed for me was building the project from xcode 6.x(mine 6.4) and then opening xcode > 7.x (mine 7.0) and then uploading app from there...

> Note:You dont need to build app from xcode 7.x . Just open the xcode
>   and select window organizer...select the build and upload...

Answer (score 1):

In my case firstly I installed last Xcode version 7.1
In my application I used GoogleMaps.framework, I opened it's bundle and removed "Executable file" and "CFSupportedPlatforms" from Info.plist, then I did the same to all my added frameworks

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed this problem, first you need to upload it with Application loader. Cause when the error happen, you can have more detail about it.
[image]

This is the Issues I got, and I found that the version numbers are the same as those library in cocoapod or other library. To solve this. Go thought all the info.plist. And change the **Bundle versions string, short**, and **Bundle version** to higher value, in my cause version number > 1.3.5.

hope this can help :D

Comment: Version number strings were the issue for us too -- but strangely, incrementing them had no effect; what finally fixed it for us was tacking an extra ".1" onto the end.

Answer (score 0):

Im stuck with the same issued, solved by download xcode 7 and submit app with it, error gone!. Hope it help everyone!.

Answer (score 0):

I was using atool from a shell script to verify and upload builds to TestFlight, then I found this thread and decided to follow @bwang's advice to use the Application Loader, and it worked!

I didn't have to download ApplicationLoader because it already comes bundled with Xcode 6.4, I just opened Xcode, then from the Dock I right clicked the Xcode icon, and then I selected "Open Developer Tools > Application Loader".

I hope Apple fixes this issue soon, because its breaking many CI tools like jenkins when using it to upload builds using atool.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue, tried all the options mentioned but no luck, Finally could solve the issue by modifying 3rd parties info.plist 
Search all info.plist files in your project and see where each and every plist has "Bundle Identifier". If not add it and submit via application loader.

Answer (score 0):

When Xcode submission isn't working, upload using Application Loader instead:

1. Archive from Xcode.
2. Save the resulting .IPA file.
3. Upload with Application Loader.

That solves this issue and many other times when Xcode upload isn't working.  Additionally, if it still fails, it will often give you a more detailed error message output.